# Redirect Query - Header not redirecting with switch

Tags: php, redirect, header, switch-statement

I'm trying to redirect my links, using a php file but when I click the links nothing happens or I get a 500 error.

I've tried redirecting websites such as https://test1.org, https://test2.org and https://test3.org using a php file with switch.

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];

switch($_GET['page']) {
    case '1':
        header('https://test1.org');
        break;
    case '2':
        header('https://test2.org');
        break;
    case '3':
        header('https://test3.org');
        break;
    default:
        echo "Hello";
}
```

Anyone know whats wrong?

I'm wanting it to redirect when someone clicks the link, example redirect.php?page=1, redirect.php?page=2 or redirect.php?page=3...etc

Comment: `header('https://test1.org');` doesn't redirect. Why do you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Location:" in your [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function call to redirect the page to the specified URL, like so:

```
header('Location: https://test1.org');
```

Comment: Thanks, but how come this does not work?

    public function redirect($path) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
            $protocol = 'https';
        } else {
            $protocol = 'http';
        }

        header("Location: $protocol://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path);
        exit;
    }

if I enter redirect('https://test1.org');

Comment: That code looks different than the code in your question. Perhaps this is a different or additional issue?

Comment: I'm tired, was having a bad day. It's sorted now.